# Do Cell Phone Repeaters have CID and LAC?

Tags: mobile-development, telecommunication

I want to detect offline mobile phones in a specific area, they are offline no GPS and no internet. I have an application and it should take an action when it detects that it is in the area.

the area may be a floor on a building or even a room.

Can I set a repeater device and wait for its signal to show up then to take an action based on the Cell Id?
knowing that I don't need the mobile phone to connect the repeater.

is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean that you want an app on the phone to detect it is in the room or building, even when the app is not connected to the internet and not using GPS.

An alternative approach to using a specialist device as you outline, and which might be worth testing, is to leverage the WiFi scanning that your device is probably already doing, even when not connected to the internet.

In Android, for example, you can register a broadcast listener for 'SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION' which will provide you a list of all the nearby wifi access points including their BSID's and SSID's ():https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult

[image]

There are permission restrictions which you need to be aware of but they are quite common ones for users - more details here:

- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-scan

Many location services use this type of approach, often to supplement the GPS info and improve accuracy.

Comment: thank you for your answer. but what if the wifi was disabled manually by the user? my approach is to set up a 2G repeater which creates signal by its own. then my question comes to know whether my app can listen to this particular signal using its CID.
I know how to get neighbors CIDs but I do not know if the repeater has one or it just meant to repeat the exact signal comes from a telecommunications tower.